# How to configurate webpack-dev-server in laravel application?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, webpack-dev-server

There is a remote server on which the Laravel application is located, I downloaded the project to the local machine and synchronized it with SFTP.

The first question is, where is it necessary to run the Dev assembly of Webpack (On a local machine or on a remote server) and how generally is it correct? If it is local machine, than how to proxy to the server with Backend?

I made a build without any problems to get all the charms of HMR, but in the public / index.html directory only, so I don’t understand how to make webpack-dev-server work with PHP, for example myapp.com/tasks?

Comment: Queue laravel-mix which has special integrated functionality with laravel in order to support HMR in blade files using the `mix('script.js')` syntax. Show us your package.json, is mix being used at all?

Comment: I don't use laravel-mix, do you recommend to use? this is the best way of solving the problem?

Comment: my package.json https://jsfiddle.net/Alex48/mt6275hv/